# Converting one row into two by minimal date in mysql

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have the next problem with a table. I need to convert the next table into the other using one single sql query:

```
id    | idal   | date        | time         | idaction 
----- | ------ | ----------- | ------------ | ----------
1001  |      1 |   2016-08-1 |     13:30:39 |        1
1002  |      1 |   2016-08-1 |     13:42:02 |        2
1003  |      1 |   2016-08-1 |     13:42:04 |        1
1004  |      1 |   2016-08-1 |     13:42:06 |        8
1005  |      1 |   2016-08-1 |     13:44:04 |        9
1006  |      1 |   2016-08-1 |     13:44:06 |        8
1007  |      2 |   2016-08-1 |     14:30:39 |        1
1008  |      2 |   2016-08-1 |     14:42:02 |        2
1009  |      2 |   2016-08-1 |     14:42:06 |        8
1010  |      3 |   2016-08-1 |     15:00:01 |        1
1011  |      3 |   2016-08-1 |     15:01:43 |        2
```

The result I want to get is the next:

```
idal | dt_act1             | dt_act8            |
-------------------------------------------------
   1 |  2016-08-1 13:30:39 |  2016-08-1 13:42:06    
   2 |  2016-08-1 14:30:39 |  2016-08-1 14:42:06
```

The meaning of this complex query is the next: I want to get for each group of the same idal values (we've got 1, 2 and 3), only those which contains at least idaction=1 and 8 (in our example, only idal 1 and 2 contains both values). At the same time, the result fields dt_act1 and dt_act8 are a datetime filed, and in main table it is splitted into date and time fields (you can use concat mysql function to join it into a datatime field, that's no problem). As you can notice, the dt_act1 is the minimum datetime for each group of same idal value for idaction=1. The same for field dt_act8 but for idaction=8. When there's no group of idal that contains both idaction 8 and 1 (in our case, idal=3), this row is not displayed.

My solution that doesn't works:

```
SELECT t1.idal, t1.dt AS dt_act1, t2.dt AS dt_act8
FROM 
      (SELECT tt1.idal, CONCAT(tt1.`date`, ' ', tt1.`time`) AS dt FROM `table` tt1 (*)
       HAVING dt = (SELECT MIN(CONCAT(tt2.`date`, ' ' , tt2.`time`)) 
                    FROM `table` tt2 WHERE tt1.idal=tt2.idal AND tt1.idaction=1
                    )
      ) t1 
   INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT tt3.idal, CONCAT(tt3.`date`, ' ', tt3.`time`) AS dt FROM `table` tt3 (**)
       HAVING dt = (SELECT MIN(CONCAT(tt4.`date`, ' ' , tt4.`time`)) 
                    FROM `table` tt4 WHERE tt3.idal=tt4.idal AND tt3.idaction=8
                    )
      ) t2
   ON t1.idal=t2.idal
```

This should be enought but doesn't works.
What's the way to do it?

SOLUTION: It remains "WHERE tt1.idaction=1" and "WHERE tt3.idaction=8" just after (*) and (**)  respectively.

Comment: This is a pivot table with a slight twist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a conditional statement (`if()` or `case`) within the `min()` expressions to get the minimums for the relevant `idactions` only. Then use the `having` clause to eliminate the records where you do not have data for both `idactions`.

Schema:

```
create table yourtable
(   `id` int not null,
    `idal` int not null,
    `date` date not null, -- don't name columns like this
    `time` time not null,  -- don't name columns like this
    `idaction` int not null
);

insert yourtable values
(1001,1,'2016-08-1','13:30:39',1),
(1002,1,'2016-08-1','13:42:02',2),
(1003,1,'2016-08-1','13:42:04',1),
(1004,1,'2016-08-1','13:42:06',8),
(1005,1,'2016-08-1','13:44:04',9),
(1006,1,'2016-08-1','13:44:06',8),
(1007,2,'2016-08-1','14:30:39',1),
(1008,2,'2016-08-1','14:42:02',2),
(1009,2,'2016-08-1','14:42:06',8),
(1010,3,'2016-08-1','15:00:01',1),
(1011,3,'2016-08-1','15:01:43',2);
```

Query:

```
select idal, 
       min(if(idaction=1,concat(`date`, ' ', `time`),null)) as dt_act1, 
       min(if(idaction=8,concat(`date`, ' ', `time`),null)) as dt_act8 
from yourtable 
group by idal 
having dt_act1 is not null and dt_act8 is not null;
```

Results:

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| idal | dt_act1             | dt_act8             |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2016-08-01 13:30:39 | 2016-08-01 13:42:06 |
|    2 | 2016-08-01 14:30:39 | 2016-08-01 14:42:06 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: @Drew you are crazy :)  but at least you did not change any of the min() expressions to max()

Comment: I didn't really do anything much

Comment: Great solution! A very small query compared with mine. Thanks a lot!